# Cannot use localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Why does local storage not work?

I have recently decided on a small website I am working on that I want to try having switchable themes. I want the themes to persist past the session and I am not at the point of logins yet, so I am looking in to local storage.

The console log here confirms the function is being run, but no storage is created for the page.

```
var main = function() {
$('#theme1').click (function () {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "1");
    console.log("click");
});
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

I have also tried `localStorage.theme = "1";` to no avail.

I am on the latest Chrome, but despite it being obvious that html 5 is supported I have checked on the w3 website [w3schools.com/html5_webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and running the code through their "Try it Yourself" system works.

Comment: Hi. Can you try to replicate the issue using http://jsbin.com please?

Comment: localStorage.setItem("theme", "1"); will be call only when element with id=theme1 is clicked.

Comment: Yes, did you click on the element `#theme1`?

Comment: How have you determined this does not work? If you execute `console.log(localStorage.getItem('theme'))` on load of your page, what do you see?

Comment: Try setting the item from your console. Then you'll be able to see whether the problem is local storage, or your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OP needs to click `#theme1`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar well obviously

Comment: Your code is just setting it, nothing to getting it from localStorage. `but no storage is created for the page` HOW do you check it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That could be the mistake. `:P`

Comment: For debugging try running localStorage.getItem() right after localStorage.setItem() and see what it returns

Comment: I am of course clicking the button. I have tried this in a startup function too.
@Praveen Kumar I am not sure how this works, I enter my code but am not sure what I do after that. "Run with JS" I would assume, but nothing happens.

Comment: @アキオ See the address bar, send us the link. :)

Comment: You said it is not set in localStorage BUT how do you check it???

Comment: You are all right I was assuming it did not work when it did. I was using the icon in the far left of the address bar which shows connection information to view cookies and local storage. This updates instantly with w3schools.org local storage but does not read local storage set from my site (why?). Also I was checking the local storage in the developer tab and seeing nothing. This is because you have to leave the local storage view and go back in to see changes.

Comment: After clicking the Button check in console whether the values are getting inserted or not by typing `localstorage()` in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading local storage on loading the page has worked.

I used the developer window console to run `localStorage.theme = "1"` as per Dan Prince's comment, and it looked like it was not working for a simple reason. You have to leave the local storage view and go back in to see changes, it does not refresh.

How I was viewing the local storage initially is clicking the icon to the left of the address in the address bar which shows cookies, local storage and connection information. This does instantly update and persist with local storage set from w3schools.org but does not read the local storage from my page for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Please refer the image for check/verify the localstorage works or not. also u wrote code for click event... click that even and then see in console. one more thing in console log

```
var main = function() {
$('#theme1').click (function () {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "1");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('theme'));
});
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

vote if u like...